# OnCheckedChanged listener for ToggleButton behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, android

I have 4 ToggleButtons which I have set to work like RadioButtons. When I check 1 button I want the other 3 to reduce in transparency (alpha).

All ToggleButtons' state isn't set by default in the activity XML, I checked.

This is the listener, all 4 of them use it:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {

            buttonView.setAlpha(1f);

            for (ToggleButton toggleButton : toggleButtons) //ArrayList containing all 4 ToggleButtons
                if(buttonView.getId() != toggleButton.getId()) //if ToggleButton selected is not the same as current value of toggleButton ...
                    toggleButton.setChecked(false);

            if (!roundNo.equals("3/3"))
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            else {
                alertDialog = Parent.moduleEnd(this, R.color.pyctures, Main.class, Start.class);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        } else
            buttonView.setAlpha(0.4f);
    }
```

The current behavior with this code is so weird I don't even know how to explain it but I'll try.

The first time the activity starts and I select a ToggleButton, it goes to the next activity WITHOUT any change in transparency in the other ToggleButtons. Now here's the weird part, when I go back to the activity and select a different ToggleButton, the ToggleButton which I selected AT THE FIRST becomes transparent but the other 2 do not.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can set other toggle buttons alpha under for loop, you can add the alpha statement with the `setChecked(false);`

Comment: @Amine I know I can workaround this but I wanted to do it the proper way, wanted to know why it wasn't working. If the post won't help em then I'll have to do the workaround :'(